# Interpreting Loss and Error in Neural Network Training

Tags: neural-network, classification, training-data

Just some general questions about training. I used a convolutional neural network for binary classification of text on a dataset of about 10,000 samples. The dataset was pretty unbalanced with about 80% of the samples in class 1. The very last image shows a model on a balanced dataset of about a few million samples doing a 14-way classification task. All models use nn.ClassNLLCriterion, momentum of 0.9, dropout, and weight decay of 0.00001:

[Here's the code for more details](https://github.com/zhangxiangxiao/Crepe)

1. For loss, I got values over 1 for validation. How bad is that? Is a loss over one big or is it reasonable?
2. Is the error y-axis unit usually in percent? So here, for the error, would it range from 0% to 0.16% or is it 0% to 16%?

[image: error]

[image: loss]

3. For the graphs below, the loss and error graphs look about the same shape. In general, should the loss and error graphs always have the same shape?
4. Are the error and loss usually on different scales?

[image: default dataset]

Comment: you need to specifiy a lot of things - like if you solve classification or regression task. And what is your loss/error function. Without that it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Ok. I added more information about my setup.

Comment: I don't see you mentioning which loss/error function you are using, and that information is fundamental. Is it cross-entropy maybe?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Sorry for the lack of information. Just updated my post again.